# How could I deal with the resolution and camera size?

Tags: camera, scale, resolution, unity-game-engine

I made a 2D game (pixel art sprites) with 256x144 resolution with 32 PPU sprites and camera size 2.25 because (Vertical size / PPU) *0.5 = camera size. And it's running quite well on 1280x720 and 1920*1080. But I made another game with 384x216 and camera size 3.375(sprites PPU 32) because I needed more room. The problem is that now it's not rendering very well on 1280x720 (the pixel art isn't accurate), only on 1920x1080 it's rendering well. Is it because 720/216= 3.333333... so it can't scale accurately because of that?

So I would like to know how can I deal with this when I scale the width and height, so I would have more room? I thought that a resolution of 16:9 would scale perfectly on any 16:9 no?

Any help is really appreciated!